# Update nested records in one sql query (active record, ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'd like to update all user preferences to a default value efficiently. The following works correctly but does not seem good enough:

```rb
Employer.find_each do |employer|
  employer.user_preferences.update_all(send_emails: employer.send_emails)
end
```

Any hints?

Comment: Can you not hit the UserPreference object directly here, maybe UserPreference.where(...).update_all(...)

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now, but you could use `joins`:

```rb
UserPreference.joins(:employer).update_all('send_email = employers.send_emails')
```